# Compare toString call against toString

Tags: javascript

what it the difference between `return toString.call(obj)` and `return obj.toString()` ?

I usually find codes with these different styles

Comment: The key difference is not about performance, but about the possibility of `toString !== obj.toString`. Tell us more about `toString` and `obj` and we will be able to answer your question…

Comment: [The toString() method returns a string representing object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString)

Comment: Those snippets return different strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`toString.call(obj)` returns the type of object, while `obj.toString()` returns the string representation of the object or the type of object if it doesn't have implemented this function.

Example:

```
var a = [5];
a.toString() // "5"
toString.call(a) // "[object Array]"
```

More details can be found on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString

Using toString() to detect object class:

```
var toString = Object.prototype.toString;

toString.call(new Date);    // [object Date]
toString.call(new String);  // [object String]
toString.call(Math);        // [object Math]

// Since JavaScript 1.8.5
toString.call(undefined);   // [object Undefined]
toString.call(null);        // [object Null]
```

UnderscoreJS uses `toString.call(obj)` instead of `typeOf` because it's faster:

```
_.isNumber = function(obj) {
    return toString.call(obj) == '[object Number]';
};
```

Comment: Using `toString` like that is the worst abuse of the global object I've seen…

Comment: It's used so just to give an example!

Comment: Still you should explain what it actually is, how it works, and how it would be done better :-)

Comment: @SpartakusMd nice !! You are right and thank you... also thank u to downvoters

Comment: @Bellash, If it answered your question, you should accept the answer to mark the question as anwered.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `toString.call(obj)` what you are actually doing is calling `window.toString(call)` which is to say you are calling the toString-function of the global object applied to you object `obj`.

When you call `obj.toString()` you call the toString-function of the actual object, which might be locally implemented - e.g. for serialization or presentation purposes - or somewhere on the prototype chain.

Try this:
`toString === window.toString; // true`

EDIT:
In node.js the global object is actually called `global`, in the browser it will remain `window`.

Comment: Just to be precise - the global object is not _always_ `window`, only when running in a browser.